# Algorithm to make the fewest call to an API

Tags: arrays, algorithm, api

In my program I will have multiple array with about 40 000 strings each with different length (from 10 to 5000 character), I need to send this array to an API wich only accept 5 000 character at a time.

In order to make the fewest API call I need to find the best combinations of string to send each time.

For example if I got an array with different lenght {3, 5, 10, 3, 4, 1, 4} and the maximum lenght of the api is 10. It should returns {10}, {4 1 5}, {3 3 4}.

I've been looking through different algorithm but no one seems to fill my need. (Subset Sum and others)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @DouglasZare In my program i will have multiple array with about 40 000 strings each with different length (from 10 to 5000 character), I need to send this array to an API wich only accept 5 000 character at a time. In order to make the fewest API call I need to find the best combinations of  string to send each time.

Comment: So, you don't just want to find subsets with sums close to a given value, you want to partition the array so that each part has a sum under the threshold. If you have an array {2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7} and aim for 10, using {2,2,2,2,2} forces the other parts to be {7} which gives a total of 6 parts, while you could use 5 parts of {2,7} instead.

Comment: Just want to make sure I do not get wrong...
1. How large the set can be?
2. If you want to find 0, and the set is {0,0,0,...0}, then you will output all 2^n subsets?

Comment: @DouglasZare Exactly Im looking to have the fewest part possible instead of having.

Comment: I suggest adjusting the title and statement of the question since I think you have a good question, but you have asked something else there. People might spend time looking for subsets that are not part of a good partition, and which have sums that are slightly greater than the maximum.

Comment: @DouglasZare you're right I just did it. Thanks !

Comment: The updated problem looks like [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing) to me. (_What_ `others` have you been looking at?)

Comment: Does "computing time" matter in this case for you?

Comment: As the optimal bin packing is NP complete, could you live with some greedy strategy? I'm curious what your reason for optimization is, is it just time, bandwidth or money?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is [Bin Packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Please find pretty nice solution in following paper: [A new algorithm for optimal bin packing](http://aaaipress.org/Papers/AAAI/2002/AAAI02-110.pdf) by Richard Korf (see example problem there)

Let us see the example for array:

```
MAXSIZE=20
[1 2 4 5 7 10 11]
```

With algorithm from referenced paper you will get:

```
[11 4 5] [10 7 2 1]
```

In short this algorithm build bin by:

1. insert into bin maximal element
2. Search for all elements that fits to volume left and maximize their sum

For example in our case first step would be:

```
# Take max element
[11]
# We have 9 volume left
# All smaller are [1 2 4 5 7] - greedy would take 7 in this case
# 4 and 5 sums up to 9 which is best fit in this case so first bin become:
[11 5 4]
# Next step: take max
[10]
# we have 10 volume left. elements lower than 10:
# [1 2 7]
# this sums up to 10 in this case giving second bin
[10 7 2 1]
```

And just some example of greedy vs mentioned one:

```
ARR = [3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 14]
BINSIZE = 20
Greedy result:
Size 3:
[[14, 5], [5, 5, 5, 3], [3]]
Mentioned alg result (size 2):
[[14, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Also you may be interested in section 'Exact algorithm' on wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like a dynamic programming problem.
Your question is similar to the [Subset Sum problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/), except that instead of just finding if such a subset exists, you want to return all such subsets.

This link seems to be close to what you need:
http://www.careercup.com/question?id=12899672

Dynamic programming is often pretty tough to wrap your head around. I'm hoping someone else will provide a thorough explanation (for me as well), but hopefully this gives you somewhere to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is the dynamic programming problem (Subset sum problem) with a variation. Not only do we want to find if the sum exists, but we also want to find all the different subsets too.

We build a 2-d boolean lookup table of sum(rows) - vs - number(cols) as is typical in many DP problems.
For finding subsets which match the sum exactly, we can call the following backtracking function on the lookup table to find possible valid sums.

```
bool backtrack(bool **subset, int sum, int a[], int n) {
    if(sum == 0) { // Sum possible
        return true;
    }
    if(sum < 0) { //Sum not possible
        return false;
    }

    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
        if(subset[sum][j] == true) {
            int val = a[j-1];

            // If val is included, can we have a valid sum?
            bool valid = backtrack(subset, sum-val, a, j-1);
            if(valid == true) {
                printf("%d ", val);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

We can call the above function in this manner to print out the number combinations, one combination in each row-

```
for(j=1; j<=n; j++) {
    if(subset[sum][j] == 1) { //For every col which is =1 for the sum'th row
       bool valid = backtrack(subset, sum-a[j-1], a, j-1);
       if(valid) {
          printf("%d\n", a[j-1]);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you? Obviously, you can change the max to be whatever you want, and probably change it to be set from the calling function, but i'll leave those choices up to you.

This worked for me, let me know if you have any issues with it.

```
List<List<string>> Chunk(List<string> inputStrings)
{
    List<List<string>> retVal = new List<List<string>>();

    List<string> sortedStrings = inputStrings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).ToList();

    while (sortedStrings.Any())
    {
        List<string> set = new List<string>();
        int max = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedStrings.Count(); ++i)
        {
            if (max == 0)
                break;
            if (max - sortedStrings[i].Length < 0)
                continue;

            set.Add(sortedStrings[i]);
            max -= sortedStrings[i].Length;
            sortedStrings.RemoveAt(i);
            --i;
        }

        if(set.Any())
            retVal.Add(set);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Note: This is C#. If needed, I can redo it in another language or with different data structures.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be resolved by a Greedy algorithm and not backtrack algorithm  that should be executed before sending string to the API.